# Careers - reply to employer ate my line breaks

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

An employer sent me a message through Careers, and when I replied, I placed several line breaks in my reply, but they were not present in the version of the text that the employer received. (I discovered this via the quoted part of the employer's email reply to me.)

I used double consecutive line breaks, which should form new paragraphs according to Markdown syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that David.  We just pushed a fix.  Thanks for the report.